# Did any sounding rocket ever reach space?

Tags: sounding-rocket

Did any sounding rocket ever reach space (Karman line 100km)

If yes then how many did and when?

Comment: Getting high up is relatively easy; it's getting going sideways fast enough to orbit that's hard. [Black Brant XII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Brant_(rocket)#History) sounding rockets have reached 1500km altitude, over three times the altitude of ISS.

Comment: By the way which one reached the highest altitude?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure, plenty of them, all the time. Most sounding rockets actually do reach space, in fact. For a complete list, I suggest you look at [Johnathan's Space Report](https://www.planet4589.org/space/lvdb/index.html), filtering out the orbital launches from there. He has an amazingly complete list!

Comment: Is there any option to query such a database online? I dont have a computer to install it, maybe it has some interface like query.wikidata?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But I can tell you in general there have been more sounding rockets reaching space than orbital rockets.